# i18n in chinese language in play 2.0 framework

Tags: internationalization, playframework-2.0

I have created messages.zh file in conf folder of play project.When i am starting the application it is showing me error mentioned below but if i copy paste the same content in messages.en it is working properly.I suppose the problem is with file extension.But what extension i should put for Chinese message file.Kindly suggest me how to resolve this issue.

This is the error which i am facing while starting the application
    string matching regex `\z' expected but`�' found

```
Thanks
```

Answer (score 1):

Check the encoding of your `messages.zh` file. I believe it needs to be UTF-8.

Comment: how to ensure that file is in UTF-8.Do i have to make some kind of declaration in messages file?

Comment: @user2800089 No, it's just how your text editor of choice saves it. In Sublime Text there's a "Save with Encoding" option. In Eclipse there's an option to change encoding under File -> Properties.